# Payment Ref(Payment Settings tab) got blocked after customized on SOOrderEntry (Sales Orders)

Tags: acumatica

My coding here after I added it on Code Editor: SOOrderEntry (Sales Orders) the Payment Ref(Payment Settings tab) got blocked.

```
 protected void SOOrder_OrderType_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
     {
       PXResult<PX.SM.UsersInRoles> user = PXSelect<PX.SM.UsersInRoles,
                               Where<PX.SM.UsersInRoles.username, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>.Select(Base);
       SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
       if(row != null)
       {
         if(user != null)
         {
           PX.SM.UsersInRoles role = user;
           if(role.Rolename == "Administrator")
           {
             e.NewValue = "CS";
             e.Cancel = true;
           }  
           else
             if(role.Rolename == "Sales 01Ao")
             {
               e.NewValue = "C1";
               e.Cancel = true;
             }
             if(role.Rolename == "Sales 01Do")
             {
               e.NewValue = "C2";
               e.Cancel = true;
             }
         }
       }
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Payment Ref is enabled only for Order Types of the ***Cash Sale*** or the ***Cash Return*** AR Document Type:

[image]
Please make sure to accordingly set up your C1 and C2 order types.